# WooCommerce display saved amount on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display total savings for each product below the "Sale" and "Regular" price, just like in the following image: https://ibb.co/T8BxH9z. Saved amount is calculated and it is visible, but for some reason my currency is not visible. So, I want to display it like this example: "Ušteda: 2291,87 kn", and right now, only the amount is showing. Link to the website: https://shop.mirakul.com.hr/.

Here is the code that I'm using. Any ideas why the currency is missing?

```
function usteda_popust() {

    global $product;
    
    if( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) {
    
        $regular_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );
        $sale_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true );
        
        if( !empty($sale_price) ) {
            $amount_saved = $regular_price - $sale_price;
            $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
            ?>
            <p style="font-size:18px;color:red;">Ušteda: <?php echo number_format($amount_saved,2, ',', '') ?></p>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'usteda_popust', 11 );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the currency simply because you get it but you don't print it.

Also you can use the `wc_price()` function to print the formatted price *(with currency)* according to your shop settings.

You can optimize your code like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'usteda_popust', 11 );
function usteda_popust() {

    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) {
        if ( $product->get_sale_price() ) {
            $amount_saved = $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price();
            ?>
            <p style="font-size:18px;color:red;">Ušteda: <?php echo wc_price( $amount_saved ) ?></p>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Here is the result:

[image]